# How do I specify types for a trait parameter?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to use a trait as a field in my struct:

```
pub trait Scene {
    type Renderer;

    fn update(&mut self);
    fn render(&mut self, r: &mut Self::Renderer);
}

struct Example {
    active_scene: *mut Scene,
}
```

When I try to use it, I get the error:

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `Renderer` (from the trait `Scene`) must be specified
 --> src/lib.rs:9:24
  |
9 |     active_scene: *mut Scene,
  |                        ^^^^^ missing associated type `Renderer` value
```

How do I specify the types in a field? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the syntax:

```
Scene<Renderer = YourRenderer>
```

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find this syntax anywhere.